# How do I view my best times for floors in Side Order?

Tags: splatoon-3, splatoon-3-side-order

When I clear a floor in Side Order faster than my previous best time, there is a small notice saying my time has been "Updated". However, I can't figure out how to see what my best times actually are.

How do I see what my best time is for a floor in Splatoon 3 Side Order?

[image]